# How to write parallel programming in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have one huge powershell script for data management which is written in powershell sequentical order , it's taking too much time in execution , I can not post the full code .... Could anyone please tell me how to do a parallel scripting in powershell so that I can save time, I have tried with start-job, stop/wait-job but it seems very difficult.

Thanks a lot.

Regards
Anshu

Comment: PowerShell jobs are the standard PowerShell way to go, easy or not. Note that parallel programming is not easy. You may ask more specific questions about your difficulties on using jobs.

Comment: Do you know for certain that running parallel jobs will increase the speed? Do you know what the constraining factor is? If you're I/O bound (moving/copying files is the slowest step), running multiple jobs in parallel likely won't gain much performance, unless you can also divide the I/O across multiple devices/interfaces. Profile before attempting to optimize - those who don't often end up optimizing the wrong things, and gain little performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.idera.com/Events/RegisterWC.aspx?EventID=297) is a webcast on several multithreading strategies in PowerShell including using PSJobs and spinning up new runspaces.  It does a good job of illustrating pros and cons of each approach.